# How is my variable unassigned, there is no path that doesn't fill it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is an entity project using stored procedure to populate complex types so I can treat them like regular entity objects.

The error it is giving me is on the `Return("Index", model);` saying `'Use of unassigned local variable 'model'`.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult FilterCallReview(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, string searchField, string searchValue)
{
    ObjectResult<MasterMxieCallReview_Result> model;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
    {
        model = spdb.MasterMxieCallReview(StartDate, EndDate);
    }
    else
    {
        if (searchField.ToLower() == "contract_number")
        {
            // Check if we need to ignore the date
            if (1 == 1)
            {
                // Run the SP with dates
                model = spdb.MasterMxieCallReview_ContractNum(StartDate, EndDate, searchValue);
            }
            else
            {
                // Run the SP without dates
                model = spdb.MasterMxieCallReview_ContractNum(null, null, searchValue);
            }
        }
        else if (searchField.ToLower() == "phone_number")
        {
            // Check if we need to ignore the date
            if (1 == 1)
            {
                // Run the SP with dates
                model = spdb.MasterMxieCallReview_ContractNum(StartDate, EndDate, searchValue);
            }
            else
            {
                // Run the SP without dates
                model = spdb.MasterMxieCallReview_ContractNum(StartDate, EndDate, searchValue);
            }
        }
    }

    ViewBag.StartDate = StartDate.ToShortDateString();
    ViewBag.EndDate = EndDate.ToShortDateString();

    // Model should never be allowed to be null at this point
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

There isn't any path where `model` is not populated to my knowledge, any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `searchField.ToLower()` is something other than `phone_number` or `contract_number`, model will not be initialized.

Comment: Blasted...  Spent like too long on this..  I added a default else statement for that section.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is (in if-else statements) the path, which will not assign the value for variable called "model", so there is a posibillity that model will be null. You should consider all the possible ways and make sure that for every case the "model" variable will have value.

There should be 'else' statement before 'else if' to make model variable assigned in every case.

Comment: It was an oversight on my part, I knew I was missing something.  If you can edit the answer to be a little more descriptive on where one might find the answer I would love to give this an upvote!